# test if text string is present with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class= "field">
   <fieldset>
         <div style="float: right">
            <button> ... </button>
         </div>
        <div class="some_class">
         Some Text
        </div>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

How can I check if "Some Text" is present using Jquery?

Comment: present inside of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking if there is any text in the div or that specific string in the div?

```
if ($.trim($(".some_class").text() == "Specific Text")) {
 //do something if specific text is found
 }


if ($.trim($(".some_class").text()).length > 0) {
 //do something if any text is found
}
```

The first will do something if the text in the div matches a specific string you are looking for, second will do something if there is any text in the div.

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jc91zdhc/)

Answer (score 0):

Just select a DOM element, and use the .text() method.
Something like:

```
var x = $("#DomeElement").text();
if(x=="Some String"){
 return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a regular expression test like this:

```
/Some Text/.test( $(this).text() )
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.field').on('click', function() {
        if( /Some Text/.test( $(this).text() ) ) {
            alert('"Some Text" was found in clicked field');
        } else {
            alert('"Some Text" was not found in clicked field');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "field">
   <fieldset>
         <div style="float: right">
            <button> ... </button>
         </div>
        <div class="some_class">
         Some Text
        </div>
   </fieldset>
</div>
<div class= "field">
   <fieldset>
         <div style="float: right">
            <button> ... </button>
         </div>
        <div class="some_class">
         Other Text 1 
        </div>
   </fieldset>
</div>
<div class= "field">
   <fieldset>
         <div style="float: right">
            <button> ... </button>
         </div>
        <div class="some_class">
         Other Text 2
        </div>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```